# How can I change Zenity dialog icon?

Tags: zenity

I want to change the default icon of any dialog in zenity , I write this line of code for ERROR Dialog

```
zenity --error --text='Icon As It Is' --window-icon=/home/ --icon-name=64.png --no-wrap
```

From above Line I succeed To remove default icon, But I want To Change the default icon with 64.png (64.png is 64*64 screen resolution image).

The default icon in the dialog box for error is ' -(Minus) sign in red colour' ,for info ' small i in blue color '. It's this icon I want to change.

I am using Linux mint 19.

Comment: According to the man page (`man zenity`) there is no `--icon-name` option. Have you tried `--window-icon=/home/64.png` like shown in the examples?

Comment: @roaima Thanks For **(man zenity )**, You can see **--icon-name=NAME ** For ERROR dialog if you type **zenity--help-error** in terminal , I Tried Your Trick But nothing happen new, Actually when we use this only ** --window-icon=/home/64.png** in zenity error then default error icon is visible, But when we use in zenity error this **--window-icon=/home/64.png --icon-name=64.png** then no any icon is visible.

Comment: What OS are you using? I really don't see an `--icon-name` in my version on Debian Linux.

Comment: @roaima I am using Linux mint 19 and I want 64.png at dialog icon, you can see, the default icon for error is **' -(Minus) sign in red colour'** ,for info **' small i in blue color '**

Answer (score 6):

1st, `--window-icon` is the icon that is displayed in the title bar of the window, not the icon within the dialog box, which is placed to the left of the text you specify.

2nd, the latter icon can be set with `--icon-name`, which is an undocumented feature that does not appear in the man page.

However, a path is not allowed here, rather just one of the predefined names "error", "info", "question", "warning", and probably "password".

On Debian, these names are translated to icon file paths, for example "info" to `/usr/share/icons/gnome/xx/status/dialog-information.png`, where "xx" is the icon resolution that is calculated to be appropriate for being displayed in the dialog depending on the screen resolution, for instance "48x48".

If you set `--icon-name` to something invalid, then no icon is displayed at all.

If you omit `--icon-name`, then a hardcoded icon in zenity is used.

So, if you want to display a different icon for instance in the "information dialog", you would have to specify `--icon-name=info` and replace the existing icon e.g. `/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/status/dialog-information.png` with one of your liking, which can have a resolution different from 48x48.

Update:

Speaking of the `gnome/` subdirectory: This corresponds to the icon theme I had selected in my appearance settings. Had I selected "Adwaita" for instance, then the subdirectory would be `Adwaita/`.

Comment: It seems like We are changing dialog icon permanently, It helps for **ERROR** and **WARNING** dialogs but for **INFO** I am writing program for multiple dialog icons at single run,

Comment: and how can i get this path as you specified /usr/share/icons/gnome/48*48/status/dialog-information.png

Comment: How to get the path? I don't know, I stumbled upon this in the past, when I was trying to accomplish the same as you.

Comment: I Tried with **locate usr/share/icon/gnome/** , It was awesome experience. Thank You For conceal the mystry

Comment: I tried with changing default icon in 48*48 but it is still not work.

Comment: 48x48 was just an example, try one of the next higher resolutions that are present, like 96x96 or 128x128. See also "Update:" in my answer.

Comment: But in 128*128 i've only 2 subdirectories apps and mimetypes and there not any icon specified for dialog icons, From  gnome/xx*xx  I tried with Every Possible resolution and It not work, here in gnome at 48*48 there is no any default icon for --info which is specified in zenity dialog , the icon is  small i letter in blue colour  but in gnome the for info is light bulb, It is suspicious, After Refer your  update for Adwaita I found In ** gnome-colour-coloumn ** subdirectory there is present  every matching dialog icon from zenity even the --info icon, So I think this is Our Right Workplace.

Answer (score 0):

```
zenity --text-info --icon-name=info --title="Window title" --width=640 --height=800 --html --filename=FILE
```

Works for me

From [the docs](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/usage.html.en):

> `--window-icon=icon_path`
>
> Specifies the icon that is displayed in the window frame of the dialog. There are 4 stock icons also available by providing the following keywords - 'info', 'warning', 'question' and 'error'.

And yes, `icon_path` is badly named ; It's definitely not a path, more like a *keyword*.

Answer (score -1):

@nst0022 is correct, use `--icon-name="foo"`, but it seems you can use any of the standard icon names in GNOME (see https://developer.gnome.org/icon-naming-spec/#names).

Thanks the folks answering this question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/526202/getting-window-icon-to-work-with-zenity